# How to remove quantity from cart page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to remove quantity from cart table.. without CSS.

[image]

Here is the price, but I want to remove quantity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php to your themes folder under your-theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php

In this file, you can remove "Price" column. You can search for 'class="product-price"' and remove that whole ''. You will need to remove respective header as well.

Comment: Can I do that with a hook?

Comment: No. You can't because if you see the template file, headers are defined hard coded. They have not used any hook there.

Comment: You can go with CSS only ....woocommerce table.cart td:nth-of-type(2), .woocommerce table.cart th:nth-of-type(2) {
display: none;
}

Answer (score 3):

This would help you in case the quantity field isn't needed and you want to use it without CSS and you don't want to change the code of many files of your theme.
This will remove the quantity from the following pages.

- Single Product Page
- Cart Page
- Product Archive Page

Add this code to functions.php of your theme to remove the quantity field for all products.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) 
{
    return( true );
}
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );`

Comment: Is it possible to don't display it only for specific products only ? based on product price per example ?

Comment: You can add an if statement inside the above function and check the price range.For example you can say if ($price>15) {return( true );}. Check this link: [Add text before product price if it's higher than a specific amount in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552886/add-text-before-product-price-if-its-higher-than-a-specific-amount-in-woocommer)

Comment: Just a note, this method is not compatible with unique cart keys to add multiple of the same product on different rows (e.g. 1x Shirt X size L + 1x Shirt X size M). Woocommerce won't allow adding the second shirt if you set sold_individually to true. This doesn't mean the solution is incorrect, just not usable in this specific scenario.