# Add text before product price for specific category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In woocommerce I am using *"[Add text before product price if it's higher than a specific amount in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552886/add-text-before-product-price-if-its-higher-than-a-specific-amount-in-woocommer/48553606#48553606)"* answer code that adds text before all prices.

How can I make this code work only for a specific product category?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to look about $product->get_category(); (or same, i dont never seen Woocommerce) and add it to last if.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work for a specific product category. The code handles parent product categories and product variations, using a custom conditional function for product categories:

```
// Custom conditional function that handle parent product categories too
function has_product_categories( $categories, $product_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); // Initializing
    $taxonomy        = 'product_cat';
    $product_id      = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;

    if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories; // Convert string to array
    }

    // Convert categories term names and slugs to categories term ids
    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // It is the Main category term and we set it.
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true : false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'prepend_text_to_product_price', 20, 2 );
function prepend_text_to_product_price( $price_html, $product ) {
    // HERE set your product category in the array
    $product_category = array('clothing');

    // Only on frontend and excluding min/max prices for variable products
    if( is_admin() || $product->is_type('variable') )
        return $price_html;

    // Get the variable product ID for product variations (as variations dont handle product categories)
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only for a specific product category
    if( ! has_product_categories( $product_id, $product_category ) )
        return $price_html;

    // Get product price
    $price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Regular price

    if( $price > 15 )
        $price_html = '<span>'.__('(GRATIS)', 'woocommerce' ).'</span> '.$price_html;

    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

You can also use `has_term()` conditional function *(not handling parent product categories)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'prepend_text_to_product_price', 20, 2 );
function prepend_text_to_product_price( $price_html, $product ) {
    // HERE set your product category in the array
    $product_category = array('clothing');

    // Only on frontend and excluding min/max prices for variable products
    if( is_admin() || $product->is_type('variable') )
        return $price_html;

    // Get the variable product ID for product variations (as variations dont handle product categories)
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only for a specific product category
    if( ! has_product_categories( $product_id, $product_category ) )
        return $price_html;

    // Get product price
    $price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Regular price

    if( $price > 15 )
        $price_html = '<span>'.__('(GRATIS)', 'woocommerce' ).'</span> '.$price_html;

    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related thread: [Add text before product price if it's higher than a specific amount in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552886/add-text-before-product-price-if-its-higher-than-a-specific-amount-in-woocommer/48553606#48553606)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
Added has_term for category to the existing answer to that question.

```
if ( has_term( 'putcategorynamehere', `'product_cat'` ) ) {
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'prepend_text_to_product_price', 20, 2 );
function prepend_text_to_product_price( $price_html, $product ) {
    // Only on frontend and excluding min/max prices on variable products
    if( is_admin() || $product->is_type('variable') ) 
        return $price_html;

    // Get product price
    $price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Regular price

    if( $price > 15 )
        $price_html = '<span>'.__('(GRATIS)', 'woocommerce' ).'</span> '.$price_html;

    return $price_html;
}
}
```